# help with exporting game as .exe

Tags: game-engine, export, scene

I've been working on a game with levels. I know how to use scenes and transferring to scenes for the levels but it's getting laggy and slow. I know I can just do 'Start Game From File'. That will start the other blend file. It works, but the problem is when I save the final game as an exe or Game Engine Runtime it doesn't work. When ever I select the option to go to the other blend file it just quits the game.

Comment: I think this has already been identified as a bug. what version of blender are you using?

Comment: 2.73 and thx for answering

Comment: Could someone link to the duplicate / other question? Thanks :)